# Why CSS selector with > sign (direct child) overrides default styles?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Could someone explain to me why CSS **>** sign (direct child) overrides the default color of all `<li>` tags in this example:

```css
ul > li {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This should be red
    <ol>
      <li>default color 1</li>
      <li>default color 2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>And this should be red also
    <ol>
      <li>default color 3</li>
      <li>default color 4</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

#### Expected result:

[image]

#### Actual result:

[image]

I know that I can fix it by adding `li { color: black; }`, but I'm wondering why `ul > li` overrides the default color for `<li>`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The issue is not the child combinator (`>`), it's the `color` property, which is inheritable.

Although the initial value of the `color` property varies from browser to browser, `inherit` is common. This means that an element's text color is inherited from the parent. You're seeing this in your code.

In contrast, the `border` property is not inheritable. Note how, unlike the text color, it applies only to your targeted `li`:

```css
ul > li {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

li { border: 1px solid inherit !important; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This should be red
    <ol>
      <li>default color 1</li>
      <li>default color 2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>And this should be red also
    <ol>
      <li>default color 3</li>
      <li>default color 4</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

To achieve your styling objective, set a default color for the `li` element. This will override `inherit`. Here's an example:

```css
ul > li {
  color: red;
}
li {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This should be red
    <ol>
      <li>default color 1</li>
      <li>default color 2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>And this should be red also
    <ol>
      <li>default color 3</li>
      <li>default color 4</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

References:

- [14.1 Foreground color: the `color` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/colors.html#colors)
- [6.2.1 The `inherit` value](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/cascade.html#value-def-inherit)

Comment: What @Ilmari Karonen said. You want to preserve the default inheriting behavior in descendants of inner li elements.

Answer (score 17):

The default value for the `color` property, for most elements, is `inherit`, not `black`. This means it takes whatever value the parent (`ol`) element has. (And that's after the `ol` inherits from the red `li`).

You would have to set an explicit colour to override it. For example:

```
ul > li li {
   color: black;
}
```

or

```
ol > li {
   color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Quentin, your answer was clearer than two previous for me, but I'll accept the most documented and most voted, probably it will be better for further readers.

Comment: That's not how accepting should work ;-) Accept the answer that was most helpful to you haha

Answer (score 4):

The `ol` is inheriting the styles. You will need to specify styles for the inner list.

Comment: And why? `ol` has totally nothing with `ul > li` selector, right?

Comment: Your `ol` is inside a `li` that has been styled red, so it will inherit that colour.

Comment: yeah, I see now, thanks for the additional explanation

Comment: Do some reading up into CSS inheritance and specificity, it'll soon click :)